# XmlNodeList to ListItemCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net

At this moment I'm reading an `XmlNodeList` into a `ListItemCollection` one node at a time using a `foreach`:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in authCompXml.SelectNodes("//Code"))
{
    CompaniesList.Items.Add(new ListItem(node.InnerText));
}
```

How can this be improved, such as without the aforementioned `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CompaniesList.Items.AddRange(authCompXml.SelectNodes("//Code")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(node => new ListItem(node.InnerText))
    .ToArray());
```